# Is there an easy way to trace where the form action goes?

Tags: javascript

A lot of websites use JS to submit form data. Is there some convenient way to trace where the form action will be submitted and what the the fields are?

I think I can manually parse through all JSs loaded in that page recursively, to find what part of JS is actually submitting the form. But that's *not* easy.

The inspector in Firefox/Chrome shows conveniently only the CSS attributes of the element, but not what script(s) are being associated with it.

Comment: No. Based on your definition, there's no *easy* way.

Comment: You could submit the form and look at the network tab in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to *easily* (without inspecting the js code itself) do that before you submit, but you could inspect the ajax call that is sent to the server to reliably see what url the request is sent to.  The network tab in the developer tools will show you this.

Alternatively, you could try using [Visual Event](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim?hl=en-US) to see scripts that will execute on certain browser events.  (note, this isn't always 100% accurate and reliable.)

Comment: Thanks Kyle. The network tab was what I was doing, until I found some fields not making sense -- I found from a few of them that the form data was preprocessed by JS before submission. The visual event looks like the magic I was looking for. I'll give that a try. But why did you note it's not reliable?

Comment: Not every js function triggered by some events shows up on some elements,  in my experience. It can also be difficult to find your code with some js frameworks like knockout or angular. It works great with jquery though. YMMV.